# how to make a list of customers with dob (date of birth)?

Tags: magento, entity-attribute-value

I'm still have problems understanding the eav in Magento.
How can I get a collection of all customers with their dob?
I tried this:

```
$collection = 
Mage::getModelResource('customer/customer_collection')
->addNameToSelect()
->joinAttribute('dob','customer_account/dob','id',null,'left')
;
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out!

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
            ->joinAttribute('dob','customer/dob', 'entity_id');
```

The explanation is here
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/15981/#t68656

Answer (score -2):

Right way will be

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
->addAttributeToSelect('dob');
```

or

```
Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('dob');
```

Comment: Nop, if you see the SQL generated when you do  
    die($collection->getSelect());      The query will be  
    SELECT `e`.* FROM `customer_entity` AS `e` WHERE (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '1')  
And 'dob' is not in the `customer_entity` table.